# Enable comment and uncomment shortcut in VS 2013 in case of .feature file

Tags: visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts, specflow

I have VS 2013 and Specflow installed. It seems the comment selection(Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C) and uncomment selection (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+U) are disabled in case of .feature file.

Doesn't matter whether it is enabled or not in the settings it is not working.

I asked the same question in the official Specflow mailing list. I got only one suggestion about I should be make sure the shortcuts are properly set up.

Did anybody experienced like this? Did anybody solve this issue?

Thanks for your help in advance!

[image: A not .feature file]
[image: A .feature file]
[image: The setup]

**Update, June 2015**
It seems this issue has been solved by the Specflow plugin 2015.1.2.

Comment: Yep same problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one workaround to this issue. You can hold the Alt key and scroll all the way down to  the area where you want to insert the comment. it will draw a very light blue line and add '#' sign for comment.